# Bulk convert PNG-24 to PNG-8 files with best quality

Tags: png, imagemagick, bulk, image-conversion, image-transparency

Can anybody recommend a good method of bulk converting a large amount of PNG-24 files to PNG-8 with as little loss of quality as possible and maintaining transparency?

I've tried [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) but the resulting images weren't quite as crisp quality as I'd like. Using [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) I was able to achieve far better results, but I can't bulk process with this tool as far as I know.

The settings I used with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) in case there's better options to use:
`convert file.png -depth 4 file-output.png`

I've also been playing with [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), but I haven't discovered a was of making sure the output images are PNG-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pngquant](http://pngquant.org) is exactly the tool for this. [It generates palettes better than ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23340).

```
pngquant --quality=0-90 *.png
```

This will convert all png files in current directory, and automatically choose number of colors to achieve quality similar to 90%-quality JPEG.

(if it doesn't accept the `--quality` switch it means you have terribly outdated low-quality version and you should upgrade).

Comment: Add `--force --ext .png` to overwrite the original files.

Comment: I'll compare this against the results of optipng soon and mark one or the other as the answer depending upon a comparison of results.

Answer (score 2):

[**GIMP**](http://www.gimp.org/) does good job optimizing reduced palettes. It has *--batch* mode and can be scripted. 
Also has multiple bindings, so you can write for example [GIMP script in Python](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html).

Comment: Thanks vartec - while I was researching how to script GIMP I came across this cool tool as it was mentioned as a plug-in for GIMP (but runs stand-alone) - [RIOT](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this great tool in my search - [RIOT - Radical Image Optimization Tool](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/)

Does everything I require and lets you see side-by-side comparison of before and after sample image before you do the batch process.

**Update**

With the latest versions of RIOT a bug has been introduced that causes some images to be output in greyscale - http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/bbpress/topic.php?id=471

Answer (score 0):

As a replacement for RIOT I've started using [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) via the following command line to process a whole directory on Windows:

```
for /r %f in (*.png) do "C:\optipng-0.7.5-win32\optipng.exe" -o3 -strip all "%f"
```